# Play movies from a USB stick to stand alone monitor

Tags: usb, monitor, execute, movie

A client asked me the following.

> I want to give a usb stick to my clients that hold a company movie.
>   They should be able to insert the usb-stick to a stand alone monitor (so no computer) and the movie should then play.

I was stumbled because I really don't have any idea how to do this.

Is there a way where I can place a movie file and some textfile that contains a code to execute the movie and play on screen?

Hope it makes any sense

M.

Comment: If the stand-alone monitor is actually a TV, it works with any compliant movie format... Otherwise it won't. I've never seen a (non-TV) monitor with USB though...

Comment: On the back of the Apple Cinema Displays are USB ports.

Answer (score 0):

No, this cannot be done without a computer. To execute a file, you need a computer to do that.

How ever, if you do have a computer, you could take the Movie, convert it to an ISO file, and then burn it to a CD and play that in a DVD player hooked up to a monitor, if the DVD player accepts the monitors output cable.

Comment: If I had a DVD player I could also burn the movie to the DVD. But I don't. I hope I can figure this out.!

Answer (score -2):

it can very easily done on any LED TVs in the market.. at present  led tv and monitor doesn't differ much.. a TV with HDMI input  can  easily used as a monitor too